# Loading items using Entity Framework where the image exists in a directory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table with products. One of the column is `product_no`. I also have a directory in my ASP.NET MVC application where I have stored the product images with the name similar to the product_no. eg. `FGFCA0004259.png`.

I want to display the products from the database which only have images in my `img` directory.

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var image_url = "http://888888.saleslife360.com/888888Images/ProductImages/";
    var img = image_url + item.product_no+ ".png";
}
```

That is my sample code I am using to retrieve the images.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: want to display the products from the database which only have images in my img directory. this is  my question. if you don't know the solution keep doing yours stuff

Comment: So what problem are you having - you have NOT asked a question

Comment: the problem of not being able to display the images in as described above

Comment: You have not shown your code for displaying them - just for creating the url's

Comment: come on.. to display the image is as simple as `<img src="@img"/>`

Comment: i want to get rid of products which don't have images in my directory from my view. since am getting all products from the db. I have images in my directory having names which correspond to the product_no. my issue is i can't find a way to get the products which have images only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153459/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-abel-masila).

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim products As List(Of Product) = New List(Of Product)
Dim imagePaths As String() = Directory.GetFiles("*.png")
Dim productNumbers As String() = imagePaths _
    .Select(Function(s) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s)) _
    .ToArray

Using context As YourDbContext = New YourDbContext
    products = context.Products _
        .Where(Function(p) productNumbers.Contains(p.product_no)) _
        .ToList
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using any ORM or not but in theory you have couple of options.

1. use image names from ImageStorage.ProductImages and send it as part
   of filter in the database query. [Select * from products where
   product_no in(imgid1,imgid2..)]
2. fetch products from database and then do a join on
       ImageStorage.ProductImages to get only the products with images.

ImageStorage is the class which will implement functionality of listing the product images from your directory.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for storing images in a directory is to save the whole url into the table.

Since in your case you're using product id a the image name. You could add a extra column of type bit on your product table, when you're saving or updating the product you could populate this column with true or false. Makes you query faster because it is all in the same read.

This is what i have done for a user profile table in my app in the past. Hope this helps!!